# TypeORM throws "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.ts(2589)" error on Repository typing

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typeorm, typescript-3.6

After update to [VSCode August 2019 (version 1.38) and Typescript 3.6](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_38#_typescript-36) i'm getting a lot of `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.ts(2589)` on [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/) repository initialization.

```
import { Connection, Repository, Entity, BaseEntity,  createConnection } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
class MyEntity extends BaseEntity {
    public id: number;
}

class Test {
    async test() {
        const connection: Connection = await createConnection();
        const myRepo: Repository<MyEntity> = connection.getRepository(MyEntity); // only here cast the error above
    }
}
```

How can I ignore or fix them?

- VSCode v1.38.0 (user setup)
- Node.js v10.11.0
- Typescript v3.4.5
- TypeORM v0.2.18

I also noticed that the error is gone if the typing is removed `: Repository<MyEntity>`

There also is the `"Excessive stack depth comparing types 'FindConditions<?>' and 'FindConditions<?>'` error on the same line.

Comment: In addition to [this issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4696) (which I assume is yours), there's also [this one](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4427) and [this one](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4696) so it's safe to assume that this is indeed a bug.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This can be solved it by using a previous version of Typescript.

First be sure that the typescript version on your workspace "npm" is lower than `3.6`. For instance:  `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "typescript": "^3.0.3"
}
```

If your workspace have `3.6.x` or greater, install a previous version typing `npm install typescript@3.4.3`

Then, **with a `.ts` file opened**, a typescript version selector will appear on status bar. (version `^3.6.x` probably being displayed)

[image]

then choose **"Use Workspace Version"** instead of **"VS Code's Version"**

[image]

Be sure that workspace version is also lower than `3.6.x` ex here version `3.4.3` is on my workspace. Or else force install a previous version as previouly mentioned

[image]

Now that version `^3.4.x` is selected, you should not have this kind of error on VS Code nor `tsc` commands.

Note: Since workspace Typescript version is compatible with TypeORM, running scripts like `npm run build` should not throw any errors cause it will use Typescript workspace binaries. The errors will only occurs on VS Code or direct `tsc` commands on terminal

Answer (score 2):

**Update** (23 September 2019):

This issue seems to have been fixed in Typescript version 3.6.3.

Source: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3194#issuecomment-529911310

Comment: Per the comments in the thread on that link, v3.6.3 does not solve the problem. If you find the TypeScript repo issues, it's still not fixed https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34933

Answer (score -2):

While using older version of typescript does the job, you can also add `skipLibCheck: true` entry in your `tsconfig.json` file as stated [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3194#issuecomment-526037271)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    ...
  }
}
```