# Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite with Emotion styled + material-ui + typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, emotion

I'm getting an error while styling a component imported from the Material-UI library with styled API (@emotion/styled).

```sh
Error:(19, 5) TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
```

I've tried downgrading to typescript 3.5.3, as some people suggested, but that didn't fix the issue.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';


const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)`
  margin:10px;
`;

interface InputProps {
  value: string;
  name: string;
  label: string;
  onChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
}

const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({ value, name, label, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <StyledTextField
      value={value}
      name={name}
      onChange={onChange}
      label={label}
    />
  );
};

export default Input;
```

Comment: Can you try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805787/typeorm-thwors-type-instantiation-is-excessively-deep-and-possibly-infinite-ts#answer-57896769

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting a generic argument as an empty object fixed the issue.

```js
const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)<{}>`
  margin: 10px
`;
```

Comment: `{}` doesn't actually mean _empty object_, it instead means _any non-nullish value_. If you want a type meaning _empty object_, the correct definition is `Record<string, never>`. This violates the [ban-types](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/ban-types/) rule. ([A more detailed explanation.](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2063#issuecomment-675156492))

In this case, however, I'm not sure that this is the best approach. MaterialUI probably provides types for their components (as Ben Seward's answer suggests), which would be a superior solution.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from Nalhin's response, this is the correct type definition, of `TextFieldProps`.

```
const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)<TextFieldProps>`
  margin:10px;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an open issue on Styled component repo.

https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/issues/1515

I met this issue without material ui.

The following method worked for me.

```
const BubbleContainer = styled(animated.div)<any>``
```